# How to store RSA key in Azure Vault

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault

I want to store my RSA key in Azure vault, is this possible?

I did not find any methods to do this.

Please find the Microsoft link for this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/keyvault-keys/?view=azure-node-latest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Azure KeyVault support storing RSA keys**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure///key-vault/keys/about-keys

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/keys/about-keys-details

**Azure SDK JavaScript**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/keyvault-keys/keyvaultkey?view=azure-node-latest#keyType

There are few ways how you can import or create RSA key in Azure Vault:

- Using AzureSDK for JavaScript https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/keyvault-keys/creatersakeyoptions?view=azure-node-latest
- Using REST API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/importkey/importkey

Comment: This is new RSA key create option in azure vault, but in my case already have RSA key and just want to store that key alone in Azure Vault.

Comment: Did you try Import options?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/keyvault-keys/importkeyoptions?view=azure-node-latest
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/keyvault-keys/jsonwebkey?view=azure-node-latest